# How do I profile the kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, profile

I'm having issues with a kworker process during system boot and I'd like to get such a nice call graph like Linus Torvalds posted [here](http://lkml.org/lkml/2010/8/15/111).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

He used [Perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) to create this but I can't tell you exactly how Linus created the graph (which parameters etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Use

> $ perf-record -g

It will create the cal graph in a file called perf.data.

and then use following commadn to view report.

> $ perf report

See man page of perf-record and report  for details.